# How do I access my TLS/HTTPS keys in order to start ListenAndServeTLS?

Tags: ssl, go, https, server, lets-encrypt

My server uses Let's Encrypt to get its TLS certificate to serve over HTTPS.

I'm electing to use the standard `net/http` package over Apache or nginx, so I used the webroot installation method, and it placed the cert files in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite`.

The issue is that the `live` directory is only accessible by the root user. My golang program requires the certs in this directory to function and serve over HTTPS.

However for obvious reasons I'm not running my program as the root user.

So that leads me to wonder: how do I access these files without having to insecurely run my web server as root permanently?

Comment: how about add reading permission for all user in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options:

- `sudo chown -R your-user /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite`

Or

- `sudo cp -a /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite ./ssl/ && sudo chown -R your-user ./ssl/`

Or

- Use a container for your app and copy your app and the certs to it, and since it will be running as root inside the container, it won't matter.

Comment: With the first option, I'm still unable to read the cert files themselves

Comment: @DougSmith you should have, did you forget passing -R to chown?

Comment: I "own" all the cert files themselves, but the group is still set as "root". Is that normal? If I try to cat any of the files as the desired user I get permission denied.

Comment: @DougSmith that's rather odd, you should be able to cat them as the user, are you running SELinux?

Comment: Ah, `live` is just simlinked to archive, I had to `chown` the archive one as well.